# Where to find computer aided tools to improve French pronunciation?

Tags: electronic-resources, pronunciation, french

I have heard of [Elsaspeak](https://elsaspeak.com/en/) which is an AI software to correct English pronunciation. Does something like this exist for French as well? If not, what would be a good computer based method to improve French pronunciation?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Note that I am not affiliated in any way to the company above, but it was the only reference I could find where they announce usage of ML algorithms to correct a learner.

Comment: What actually qualifies something as AI software? I've looked at ElsaSpeak, and it appears the "AI-powered" commentary is just a marketing gimmick, in my opinion. The actual features offered by the app are no different than any other analysis program.

Comment: thanks, yes while looking around and trying some apps, i see that the ML algos are mostly poor, testing my best pronounced french matches most app's correction algorithm rather fast, but testing with a well pronounced "blablaba..." looks not to match the expectation of the algorithm. maybe i should rephrase my question, where can i find examples of matching 2 .wav files (one of my pronounciation one with native speaker, and detect the weak points in my version)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry I have no answer for you, but ElsaSpeak sounds cool. Do you have experience using it? Does it help?

Comment: elsaspeak only offers english support as i understand. but I found 2 apps (Busu and Rocket Languages which offer some way to track French vocal progress. Still it is rather simple (it does not give feedback and to pass the recording test is not too challenging)